# Can't install last version of pandas (1.0.3)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, installation, python-3.6

For last two days, 24/7 I'm trying to deal with the problem of installation of pandas 1.0.3 package within Python 3.6.0. I will try to describe the whole situation below.

In my PyCharm I saw that I can upgrade pandas from 0.25.3 I was using to 1.0.3, but once I tried it an error has occurred.

[possibility of an upgrade of pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM4SR.png)

[an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ab0x1.png)

Firstly, I checked the default version of my python in the terminal:

```
In: python -V
Out: Python 2.7

In: python3 -V
Out: Python 3.6.0
```

Using [this guid](https://dev.to/malwarebo/how-to-set-python3-as-a-default-python-version-on-mac-4jjf) I have change the default python version for python 3.6. Which lead to this thing:

```
In: python -V
Out: Python 3.6.0
```

But still I can't install/upgrade pandas to version 1.0.3.

I've tried these commands in the terminal:

```
pip install pandas
pip3 install pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.3
pip3 install pandas==1.0.3
```

Same commands via `sudo`

```
pip install /path_to_wheel
```

Always I got the same error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==1.0.3 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0rc2, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0rc0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas==1.0.3
```

Please help. I do not know why it happens :(

**UPDATE:**

Also not working:

```
python3 -m pip install /Users/username/Downloads/pandas-1.0.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl 
Processing ./Downloads/pandas-1.0.3-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl
ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.6.0 not in '>=3.6.1' –
```

Comment: I had a similar problem. It worked after I upgraded pip. Try `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip` Or maybe with pip3 instead of pip.

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because pandas 1.0.x (and 1.1.0x) requires Python 3.6.1 or later. You are using Python 3.6.0. This can be seen in the error message you get :

```
ERROR: Package 'pandas' requires a different Python: 3.6.0 not in '>=3.6.1' –
```

This should be solved if you update your Python version.

You can see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/fd9ceb9dce3d62d8a9caa6ba7c127b512939452e/setup.py#L768) the Python 3.6.1 requirement starting from pandas 1.0.0.